# ColdFusion error using IsDefined(): parameter must be a syntactically valid variable name

Tags: coldfusion

In ColdFusion, when I call `IsDefined("root.L1[1].L2")`, I am getting the following error:

> Parameter 1 of function IsDefined, which is now root.L1[1].L2, must be a syntactically valid variable name.

This is a valid variable name, so what gives?

Here is my simplified test code:

```
<cfscript>
  root = StructNew();
  root.L1 = ArrayNew(1);
  root.L1[1] = StructNew();
  root.L1[1].L2 = "foo";

  WriteOutput("root.L1[1].L2 is: #root.L1[1].L2#<br/>"); //no exception

  if(IsDefined("root.L1[1].L2")) //exception!
    WriteOutput("It is defined!");
  else
    WriteOutput("It is not defined!");
</cfscript>
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've done CF, but that doesn't look like "a variable name" to me. It looks like a variable name (root) plus a property access, an indexer lookup, and then another property access. In other words, it's not a simple variable name, it's actually making at least three method calls under the covers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
StructKeyExists(root.L1[1],"L2")
```

instead of isDefined()

I vaguely recall there being issues with complex variables with isdefined(), but I can't recall the version.

Comment: but what if i don't know for sure that root.L1 has any elements? is there any alternative? I can check `IsDefined("a.b.c.d")` even if `b` doesn't have a `c` element, but i guess that doesn't work if there is an array in the structure.

Comment: You might need to stack your checks with AND statements then. Check the array length [using something like arrayLen(root.L1) GT 0] before doing the final structKeyExists above.

Comment: First, sorry for how many edits there are, I'm not used to not being able to press enter. Anyway, Here's what I'm trying to do: `<cfif StructKeyExists(cfcatch.tagContext[i],'raw_trace')>` I get element at position 2 cannot be found. Well duh, why doesn't it send back false? Then I tried `<cfif StructKeyExists(cfcatch.tagContext, i)>` and that says `You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class coldfusion.runtime.ExceptionInformation as a structure with members`. WTFCF?

Comment: This helped me. However my syntax was     <cfif structKeyExists(keyvaluePair['parentKey'],"childKey")>

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in a follow-up comment you should stack the logic checks a la:

```
    if(arrayLen(root.L1) gte 1 AND structKeyExists(root.L1.[1],'L2')){ }
```

The parser will skip the second logical argument if the first fails, so you won't get an error on the second if the first passes.